# ATTiny85 Serial communication with Bluetooth Module

Tags: serial, softwareserial, attiny, attiny85

For a simple project I would like to use a ATTiny85 connected to a HC-06 Bluetooth Module so it can talk to my Android phone.

I wrote a code for my Arduino Uno and worked as expected. When I changed the code to use on my ATTiny85 I got an error saying that `'Serial' was not declared in this scope` and assumed that the ATTiny does not support Hardware Serial.

I need to read a String when received and sleep the MCU when not receiving. I went to use SoftwareSerial and was not able to get a String, just the first char.

I approached it in some was, like defining a `char string[10];` as global and `string[i] = mySerial.read(); i++;` inside the loop, but it keeps not working. Whether it is the sleep, or my work to read data, I couldn't make it work.

Can someone provide a way to put a ATTiny85 to sleep, wake up to receive a String through Serial and sleep til the next data through Serial, please?

To sleep I'm using

```
void sleep() {
  GIMSK |= _BV(PCIE);                     // Enable Pin Change Interrupts
  PCMSK |= _BV(PCINT3);                   // Use PB3 as interrupt pin
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);

  sleep_enable();                         // Sets the Sleep Enable bit in the MCUCR Register (SE BIT)
  sei();                                  // Enable interrupts
  sleep_cpu();                            // sleep

  // woke up
  cli();                                  // Disable interrupts
  PCMSK &= ~_BV(PCINT3);                  // Turn off PB3 as interrupt pin
  sleep_disable();                        // Clear Sleep Enable bit

  sei();                                  // Enable interrupts
}

ISR(PCINT3_vect) {

}
```

And my loop is something like

```
char inputString[10];
int i = 0;

void loop() {
  sleep();

  if (serial.available() > 0) {
    char inputChar = serial.read();
    if (inputChar == '2') {    //Char to break
      //Do something and reset i
    } else {
      inputString[i] = inputChar;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: You could easily overflow your buffer here. It’s a fixed 10 bytes, but nothing checks to see if you’ve filled it. You might be just trashing the memory by writing outside of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello,

I think you should do this:

```
char inputChar = '';    //this in global
while (serial.available()) {
    inputChar = serial.read();
    if (inputChar == '2') {    //Char to break
        //Do something and reset i
    } else {
        inputString[i] += inputChar;    //= to +=
    }
    i++;
}
```